# Facebook Login Error libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift, nsexception

I am getting the following error while building the app.  Anyway to fix this issue.

See the error details the end of application launch' *** and in the image.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if(FBSDKAccessToken.current()==nil){
            print("Not Logged In")
        }
        else{
            print("Logged In..")
        }

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.delegate = self
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","users_friends"]
        loginButton.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

        if(error == nil){
            print("login complete")

        }
        else{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("Logged out..")
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhs9V.png)

Comment: Any more log from the console before the exception?